# Tikz - Fill circle/sinus area

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a circle separated in 4 part by two sin functions. And I'd like to fill each part with a different color. But I don't know how to make the area follow the sinus

[image]

What I've done yet:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (m1) at (1,2.6) {};
\draw[fill=gray!50] (m1) circle (1 and 0.5);

\draw[fill=blue!40] (m1) circle (0.3);
\draw[fill=blue!70] (m1) circle (0.25);

% Horizontal sin
\draw[smooth, samples=200, domain=-0.1:2.1, color=red!70] (m1)
plot(\x, {sin(\x*10 r)*0.03+2.6});
% Vertical sin
\draw[smooth, samples=200, domain=2:3.2, color=red!70] (m1)
plot({sin(\x*10 r)*0.03+1}, \x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What packages are you using? (I think I'm missing one in my code.)

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so that it compiles fine for everybody. In the future, remember to add `\documentclass` any packages needed, `\begin{document}` and other code needed to run the **Minimal Working** Example.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. :s I edited my post

Comment: @heather I don't think so. Code works fine without any `\usetikzlibrary{}`.

Comment: Which circle? All 3?

Comment: the blue ones, I did specify, because if I can do it for one, I can do it for all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipping helps to get different colors in the four quadrants of the two circles:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  smooth,
  samples=200,
]
  \coordinate (m1) at (1,2.6);
  \def\llx{-.1}
  \def\lly{2}
  \def\urx{2.1}
  \def\ury{3.2}
  \def\PlotSinV{plot[domain=\lly:\ury]({sin(\x*10 r)*0.03+1}, \x)}
  \def\PlotSinH{plot[domain=\llx:\urx] (\x, {sin(\x*10 r)*0.03 + 2.6})}

  % Large grey ellipsis
  \draw[fill=gray!50] (m1) circle (1 and 0.5);

  % Clip right half
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (m1) \PlotSinV -- (\urx, \ury) -- (\urx, \lly) -- cycle;

    % Clip upper half, intersection with right half => quadrant I
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (m1) \PlotSinH -- (\urx, \ury) -- (\llx, \ury) -- cycle;
      \draw[fill=blue!40] (m1) circle (0.3);
      \draw[fill=blue!70] (m1) circle (0.25);
    \end{scope}

    % Clip lower half => quadrant II
    \begin{scope}
      \clip(m1) \PlotSinH -- (\urx, \lly) -- (\llx, \lly) -- cycle;
      \draw[fill=orange!40] (m1) circle (0.3);
      \draw[fill=orange!70] (m1) circle (0.25);
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  % Clip left half
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (m1) \PlotSinV -- (\llx, \ury) -- (\llx, \lly) -- cycle;

    % Clip lower half => quadrant III
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (m1) \PlotSinH -- (\urx, \lly) -- (\llx, \lly) -- cycle;
      \draw[fill=green!40] (m1) circle (0.3);
      \draw[fill=green!70] (m1) circle (0.25);
    \end{scope}

    % Clip upper half => quadrant IV
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (m1) \PlotSinH -- (\urx, \ury) -- (\llx, \ury) -- cycle;
      \draw[fill=magenta!40] (m1) circle (0.3);
      \draw[fill=magenta!70] (m1) circle (0.25);
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}

  \draw[red!70] (m1) \PlotSinH (m1) \PlotSinV;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]